# WiX patching not updating files correctly

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3, wix3.5

My "admin-image" style WiX test patches are failing to update the existing installation correctly. When using msiexec /lx, I get the following information related to patching "fi_executable.exe":

```
MSI (s) (88:E0) [12:32:41:716]: Baseline: Patch {E244BAC8-7E62-4406-889B-4B67A4EA7369} modified fi_executable.exe with full-file update.
MSI (s) (88:E0) [12:32:41:716]: Baseline: First patch for fi_executable.exe, saving native info.
MSI (s) (88:E0) [12:32:41:716]: Baseline: fi_executable.exe version for baseline at patch Native: 6.0.5803.11, 1033, 53840.
...
MSI (s) (88:E0) [12:32:41:716]: Baseline: fi_executable.exe version for baseline at patch {E244BAC8-7E62-4406-889B-4B67A4EA7369}: 6.0.5830.99, 1033, 47104.
...
MSI (s) (88:E0) [12:32:41:763]: {E244BAC8-7E62-4406-889B-4B67A4EA7369} File: fi_executable.exe ValData: 6.0.5830.99 1033 47104
...
MSI (s) (88:E0) [12:32:41:763]: Native File: fi_executable.exe ValData: 6.0.5803.11 1033 53840
...
MSI (s) (88:E0) [12:32:42:543]: The file represented by File table key 'fi_executable.exe' has no eligible binary patches
```

So even though the version number is changing, and Windows Installer notes that the patch modifies the file, Windows Installer is not recognizing that there should be an update to the executable.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tested the upgrade with complete MSI files first before trying with the patch? Patching is just a delivery mechanism for upgrades packaged in a more compressed fashion, if the full MSI upgrade doesn't work, neither will the patch.

Comment: Here are some patching tips: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23450821. Not by any means complete, and somewhat chaotic.

Answer (score 3):

Try to install your patch with this command line:

```
msiexec /p patch.msp /qb REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=omusa
```

Without these additional parameters, my patch failed to install correctly: it didn't update any files.